# tkinter and library PhotoImage

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, photoimage

This code works:

```
img = PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")

Label(root, image=img).pack()
```

How come this way doesn't work?

```
Label(root, image=PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")).pack()
```

Is it not possible to have everything in one line?

Comment: But also with other libraries must be bound to a reference?

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't about *syntax* -- it's about *garbage collection*.  In your shortened form:

```
Label(root, image=PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")).pack()
```

the pointer to the image returned by `PhotoImage()` never gets saved, so the image gets garbage collected and doesn't display.  In your longer form:

```
img = PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")

Label(root, image=img).pack()
```

You're holding onto a pointer to the image, so everything works fine.  You can convince yourself of this by wrapping the working code in a function and making `img` local to that function:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def dummy():
    img = PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")

    Label(root, image=img).pack()

dummy()

mainloop()
```

Now, it won't display anymore because `img` disappears when the function returns and your image gets garbage collected.  Now, return the image and save the returned value in a variable:

```
def dummy():
    img = PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")

    Label(root, image=img).pack()

    return img

saved_ref = dummy()
```

And your image works again!  The common fix for this looks something like:

```
def dummy():
    img = PhotoImage(file="Image.gif")

    label = Label(root, image=img)
    label.image_ref = img  # make a reference that persists as long as label

    label.pack()

dummy()
```

But you can see we've moved a long way away from a one-liner!

Comment: thanks cdlane for answer. Excuse the example: Is it right if I say that the Photoimage library works using a dictionary, then key and value?

Comment: @Kaa, what you're saying seems a non sequitur at best -- incorrect at worst.

Answer (score 0):

On the first version, `img` keeps the reference to the image.

On the second version, there is not reference to that image and `pack()` returns `None`

Comment: thanks Billal Begueradj for answer, It's not for a reason for improvement I was just wondering why it was mandatory to have a reference, and understand if you could help it